# Kohana Exception: A valid cookie salt is required

Tags: php, kohana

Проблема с captcha kohana... сделал все, как нужно вроде, но выдает такую ошибку. Скажите, как исправить можно?

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Cookie::$salt = '1234567890..'; //` [google](https://www.google.com/search?q=kohana+cookie+salt)

Прописать в `bootstrap.php` до подключения модулей

Comment: Captcha так работать не будет...((

Comment: @zhekonya, специально проверил, всё работает  
эту строчку надо было добавить до подключения модулей

Comment: да работает...спс...просто у меня еще ошибка была