# Установил kohana, после удалил файл install.php и ошибка

Tags: kohana

Вот ошибка

[image: img]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Cookie::$salt = '1234567890..'; //` [google](https://www.google.com/search?q=kohana+cookie+salt)

Прописать в `bootstrap.php` до подключения модулей

*[Всего-то](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/150886/php-kohana-exception-a-valid-cookie-salt-is-required) поискать "kohana cookie salt" по этому же сайту.*

Comment: написал, и после опять ощибка Kohana_HTTP_Exception [ 404 ]: The requested URL mackay was not found on this server.

Comment: @trix, проверяйте маршруты, контроллеры, экшены

Comment: только что установил кохану, котроллер и экшен 1, стандартный. Там все правильно

Comment: kohana не падает после установки, а значит там не всё правильно  
по какому пути заходите на сайт?

Comment: http://mackay.kz/mackay/

Comment: пройдитесь по файлу ``bootstrap.php``, его надо настроить  
как минимум ``'base_url' => '/mackay/'`` в ``Kohana::init``

Comment: спасибо, да, там стояла /Kohana/